# Quoting Code-Block with linewraps breaks the code

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, blockquote

When quoting a code-block with lines wrapping due to their length, applying the blockquote-format results in breakage:

```
for (GroupMembers groupMembers : groupMembersList) {
    Notification notification = this.notificationService.createNotification(personid, true, "/section/listing/" + groupCanvas.getMcanvasid() + "?note=" + mnotes.getMnoticesid(), subject, text,
        type, groupSection.getMsectionid(), groupCanvas.getMcanvasid(), mnotes.getMnoticesid(), mnotes.getMnotecolor());
```

^ this code-block  will result in the following markdown, when pressing Ctrl+Q after selecting it:

```
>     for (GroupMembers groupMembers : groupMembersList) {
>         Notification notification = this.notificationService.createNotification(personid, true,
> "/section/listing/" + groupCanvas.getMcanvasid() + "?note=" +
> mnotes.getMnoticesid(), subject, text,
>             type, groupSection.getMsectionid(), groupCanvas.getMcanvasid(), mnotes.getMnoticesid(),
> mnotes.getMnotecolor());
```

Instead it should result in the following:

```
>      for (GroupMembers groupMembers : groupMembersList) {
>                 Notification notification = this.notificationService.createNotification(personid, true, "/section/listing/" + groupCanvas.getMcanvasid() + "?note=" + mnotes.getMnoticesid(), subject, text,
>                         type, groupSection.getMsectionid(), groupCanvas.getMcanvasid(), mnotes.getMnoticesid(), mnotes.getMnotecolor());
```

The current algorithm for applying `>` seems a little overenthousiastic...